Is there a way to include HTML and CSS to be used in an npm package?
I have an npm package that uses HTML and CSS to create custom elements from templates, and I'm trying to figure out how to include those files effectively.
I currently have an API serving the contents but would like to move everything into the package if possible to minimize external dependencies.

What exactly did you try? npm packages can incorporate arbitrary files.

You can just use the files field in your package.json script to include the HTML and CSS templates you want. Here's an example:
{
  "name": "my-package",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "dist/index.js",
  "files": [
    "dist",
    "src/styles",
    "src/templates"
  ],
  "scripts": {
    "build": "your-build-command"
  },
  "dependencies": {}
}

If you're using a tool like Webpack, you can just use html-loader and CSS-loader to have typescript to load the files dynamically. Don't forget to use npm publish when you're done.

Does this looko correct for the usage of html-loader?
import html from "./htmlpage.html";
let htmlstring = require('html-loader!./htmlpage.html');

@jon booream. That looks fine. Check for syntax here: https://webpack.js.org/loaders/html-loader/
